# $\sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k+1}$ to differential equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, recreational-mathematics

I want to use $S = \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k+1}$ and get the relation $(a^2+1) S'=1−aS$. So far I am just getting $\frac{dS}{da} = \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k} (2k+1)$, which I am not seeing how to use with S to get that relation. What should I do to progress and get the desired relation?

Comment: I think what you want is $$S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k+1} $$

Comment: I have that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be
quite straightforward
once the double factorials
are replaced.

$S(a) 
= \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \dfrac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k+1}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} 
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2k-2j)}{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2k+1-2j)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(2j)}{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(2j+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(2j)^2}{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(2j)(2j+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{4^k(k!)^2}{(2k+1)!}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
S(a) 
&= \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \dfrac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k+1}\\
&= \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \dfrac{4^k(k!)^2}{(2k+1)!} a^{2k+1}\\
S'(a)
&= \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \dfrac{4^k(k!)^2}{(2k)!} a^{2k}\\
a^2S'(a)
&= \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \dfrac{4^k(k!)^2}{(2k)!} a^{2k+2}\\
&= \sum_{k=1} ^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{4^{k-1}((k-1)!)^2}{(2k-2)!} a^{2k}\\
(a^2+1)S'(a)
&= \sum_{k=1} ^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{4^{k-1}((k-1)!)^2}{(2k-2)!} a^{2k}+\sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \dfrac{4^k(k!)^2}{(2k)!} a^{2k}\\
&= 1+\sum_{k=1} ^\infty \left((-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{4^{k-1}((k-1)!)^2}{(2k-2)!}+(-1)^k \dfrac{4^k(k!)^2}{(2k)!}\right) a^{2k}\\
&= 1+\sum_{k=1} ^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{4^{k-1}((k-1)!)^2}{(2k-2)!}\left(1- \dfrac{4k^2}{(2k)(2k-1)}\right) a^{2k}\\
&= 1+\sum_{k=1} ^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{4^{k-1}((k-1)!)^2}{(2k-2)!}\left(\dfrac{2k(2k-1)-4k^2}{(2k)(2k-1)}\right) a^{2k}\\
&= 1+\sum_{k=1} ^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{4^{k-1}((k-1)!)^2}{(2k-2)!}\left(\dfrac{-2k}{(2k)(2k-1)}\right) a^{2k}\\
&= 1+\sum_{k=1} ^\infty (-1)^{k} \dfrac{4^{k-1}((k-1)!)^2}{(2k-1)!} a^{2k}\\
1-aS(a) 
&= 1-a\sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \dfrac{4^k(k!)^2}{(2k+1)!} a^{2k+1}\\
&= 1+\sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \dfrac{4^k(k!)^2}{(2k+1)!} a^{2k+2}\\
&= 1+\sum_{k=1} ^\infty (-1)^{k} \dfrac{4^{k-1}((k-1)!)^2}{(2k-1)!} a^{2k}\\
\end{array}
$

and they match.

Comment: Great explanation. Now I'm just wondering, how did someone possibly come up with that relation as it involves so much algebra?

Comment: The big picture is that if $a_n$ satisfies a linear recurrence with polynomial coefficients, the power series will satisfy a linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by $a_n$ and what recurrence relation specifically?

Comment: @Robert Israel So in $a_n = (2n)!!/(2n+1)!!$ then $a_n = a_{n-1}(2n)/(2n+1)$. This has rational coefficients, not polynomial coefficients. Is $(2n+1)a_n = 2na_{n-1}$ what you mean?

Comment: Write it as $(2n+1) a_n = (2n) a_{n-1}$ and they are polynomial coefficients.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reference where the general case is worked out?

Comment: Try Wilf, [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of that, I've had it for years. Also A=B.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write $a^2 S'$ and $a S$ as sums involving $a^{2k}$ rather than $a^{2k+2}$, so you can combine the terms.

Comment: I keep getting this cheeky term in the sum, (2k+1). Not really sure how to deal with it. My sums look like $S' = \sum S_k a^{2k} (2k+1)$, $S = \sum S_k a^{2k+1}$ and I tried factoring an $a^2$ out of the terms you mentioned but that doesnt really help.

Comment: As usual, your advice works.