# $\sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k+1}$ derivative relation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

I want to use $S = \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k+1}$ and get the relation $(a^2+1) S'=1−aS$. So far I am just getting $\frac{dS}{da} = \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k} (2k+1)$, which I am not seeing how to use with S to get that relation. What should I do to progress and get the desired relation?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this once here? -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749355/sum-k-0-infty-1k-frac2k2k1-a2k1-to-differential-equ?rq=1

Comment: Oops my computer must have glitched. So sorry!